# Courtesy Redirect with NancyFx

Tags: angularjs, redirect, nancy

We are battling trying to get html5mode working with AngularJs, the last hurdle is to recreate the courtesy redirect that [IIS does](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298408) as such:

**Request**

```
GET http://localhost/foo HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: ws7-agentry2
```

**IIS Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://localhost/foo/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 17:09:20 GMT
Content-Length: 147

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://localhost/foo/">here</a></body>
```

The issue is that regardless of the request containing a trailing slash or not, the request object in the Nancy pipeline is identical.  Since we can not differentiate between the two, we can not return a redirect without causing an infinite loop of redirects.  We have tried to use url rewrites to accomplish this but to no avail, ideally I would like to get the raw url.

thanks in advance

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: When hosting in IIS, the http pipeline returns a 301 for a web application when a trailing forward slash is NOT initially requested, I would like to accomplish the same with NancyFx.  However in the NancyBootstrapper on Request method, you can not differentiate between the web request with a trailing forward slash and without to return a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs to achieve the same results, which is to get html5mode working with IE9 & NancyFx, had to build a httpmodule as this article [shows](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153462.aspx?Is%20it%20possible%20to%20disable%20the%20courtesy%20301%20redirect%20for%20URL%20requests%20that%20lack%20a%20trailing%20slash%20) though I believe the title is wrong:

```
public class CourtesyRedirectModule : IHttpModule {
    public void Dispose() {}

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/");
    }
}
```